# how to find a word in a file which matches the input from html, and then delete the entire string

Tags: php, html

```
`<?php
$aclname = $_POST['aclname'];
$file = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$exclude = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $aclname) !== FALSE) {
         continue;
    }
    $exclude[] = $line;
}
echo implode("\n", $exclude);
?>
```

Please help me with a code to open a file. Find a word in a file which matches the input variable from html, and then delete the entire string.

$word = $_POST['word'];

possible matches of $word from the file should be found and the entire string should be deleted.

**example:**

*input*

```
$word = hello
```

**strings in the file**

```
hello world

hi world

how are you world.
```

**output**

```
hi world

how are you world
```

Comment: Welcome to stack? what code till you tried?

Comment: Hi @A-2-A i have added the coding in the question above, please help

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read the entire content of that file

```
$str=file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

Then replace the message you want to delete

```
//replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
$str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);
```

Then write it on the file

```
//write the entire string
file_put_contents('file.txt', $str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @urfusion - it would be better if I could delete the entire line and @ saadeez - I would not like it to be replaced. please help me out on figuring a solution.

Comment: @lucky - You are welcome. In my code use blank quotation instead of variable `$deletedFormat`, now your code will be like `$str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);`

Comment: thanks again, I want the program to understand the input received and then match it with a word in a line. if it matches then the line should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` for replacing value.

```
    $word = $_POST['word'];   
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $data = preg_replace($word, '', $data);
    file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

Comment: OP wants to remove the line not only the word.

Comment: Hi. although I want the entire line to be removed. I tried your coding as well, unfortunately it didn’t work. I would appreciate if you could help me through this.